# ksh93 as default shell via ssh

Tags: ssh, shell, ksh

I'm a big fan of ksh93.  My hosts' shell account doesn't allow me to configure `.login`, `.profile` or `chsh` to change my default shell. As it is, I am dropped into jailshell-3.2 and I have to invoke `/bin/ksh93` manually.

Are there any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
ssh -t user@host ksh -i
```

Comment: Works! Phew, thanks you have saved the day.  

A great tip which I will definitely use in the future.

Comment: This works for most cases, though if what you're trying to avoid is the side effects from the user's `.rc` files (`.login`, etc), this won't work because the specified command is still executed under the user's default shell.